# Iterate and retrieve data from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database looks like this

[image]

Rockport and Palmont are the cities and they have locations, the locations are many but i'm just giving an example - So I wanted to retrieve the locations name and population

I came up with this code which works and shows me "Location1" for each city

```
$("#button").click(function() {
      var dbref = firebase.database().ref();
    dbref.once("value")
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(datasnap) {
          var Location = datasnap.child("Location1/name").val();
          var Population = datasnap.child("Location1/population").val();             
          $( "#table" ).append( "<tr><td>" + Location + "</td><td>" + Population + "</td></tr>" );    
        })
      })
  });
```

And the output for my html table is

```
SILVERTON   197
ROSEWOOD    213
```

It doesn't show "Location2" names and population because I didn't mention it obviously, In line 6 and 7 I can make it like this

```
var Location = datasnap.child("Location2/name").val();
var Population = datasnap.child("Location2/population").val();
```

but like I said the locations can be as many as '20' and I need to write all locations down?

any way to outcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the child data of each city. Firebase's `Snapshot` has a method `forEach()` that makes this easy. You already use this to loop over the cities, but you should also use it to loop over the locations in each city:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  var dbref = firebase.database().ref();
  dbref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(citysnap) {
      citysnap.forEach(function(locationsnap) {
        var Location = locationsnap.child("name").val();
        var Population = locationsnap.child("population").val();             
        $( "#table" ).append( "<tr><td>" + Location + "</td><td>" + Population + "</td></tr>" );    
      });
    })
  })
});
```